# Laravel dd() and view 404 doesnt render

Tags: laravel

I tried to dd some data but it just show full html code

```
public function checkPayment()
{
    $payment = Payment::where('status', 3)->get();
    dd($payment[0]->order->account_executive->name);
    return view('admin.order.paymentCheck', compact('payment'));
}
```

but it render like this [image: Error not rendering]

i tried dd(1) or dd('a') but the result is the same.

i expected dd like this
[image]

Comment: Have you saved the filename like so: `paymentCheck.blade.php`, if you have then can you share that code

Comment: $payment is not an array, it's a collection. Try $payment = Payment::where('status', 3)->first(); and then dd($payment->order->account_executive->name) and see if that gives you better data.

Comment: yes i know it's not an array. the problem is the dd render. it doesnt show the usual dd

Comment: have you tried composer update?

Comment: i tried composer update and delete vendor folder then composer install. but still not working @Smankusors

Comment: check the response header (Content-Type), maybe you have some middleware that changes the header?

Comment: thanks dude it's working @Smankusors.
i changed header at routes/api.php i didnt know it change the whole routes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

answers from [smankusors](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6241697/smankusors)

remove the header(Content-Type) in provider or middleware or routes.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to access your collection as if it's an array, which may be causing an error that is not allowing the dd to execute properly. If you want to dd the first member of your $payments collection, try this:

```
$payments = Payment::where('status', 3)->get();
dd($payments->first()->order->account_executive->name);
```

See if that helps and let me know if it's still dumping out the html. It shouldn't.

Comment: it still dumping out the html.

Comment: If you comment out the return view line, does it still do this? If so, it's happening before the controller method is being executed and the issue is not in this segment of the code. Can you check and let me know?

Comment: i already know the answer. it because  header (Content-Type) in my api route. 
i dont know the web route share the same header with api route. thanks for helping